# Django: using a settings folder; ImportError: cannot import name 'QUEUE_NAME'

Tags: python, django, trading

I am following this install for this project:
https://github.com/IntelligentTrading/data

The project uses a settings folder rather than a settings.py file. (This makes this error rather unique compared to a settings file not being found, for instance). The data from the settings/vendor_services_settings.py is what needed and causes the error. The migration command seems to look only in the settings/local_settings.py file.

I've gotten up to migration: (I am in a virtualenv)

```
python manage.py migrate
INFO:settings:Deployment environment detected: LOCAL
INFO:settings:Importing vendor_services_settings
INFO:settings:LOCAL environment detected. Importing local_settings.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cerulean/.virtualenvs/ITF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cerulean/.virtualenvs/ITF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/cerulean/.virtualenvs/ITF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/cerulean/.virtualenvs/ITF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/cerulean/.virtualenvs/ITF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/cerulean/.virtualenvs/ITF/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/cerulean/Code/data-sources/apps/indicator/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apps.indicator.models.events_elementary import EventsElementary
  File "/home/cerulean/Code/data-sources/apps/indicator/models/events_elementary.py", line 17, in <module>
    from apps.signal.models.signal import Signal
  File "/home/cerulean/Code/data-sources/apps/signal/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apps.signal.models.signal import Signal
  File "/home/cerulean/Code/data-sources/apps/signal/models/signal.py", line 15, in <module>
    from settings import QUEUE_NAME, AWS_OPTIONS, BETA_QUEUE_NAME, TEST_QUEUE_NAME, PERIODS_LIST
ImportError: cannot import name 'QUEUE_NAME'
```

On line 21 of /settings/local_settings.py, it says to pass including this data if 'LOCAL', rather than pass the required data as the other cases in the if statement do:

```
else: # LOCAL
     pass # see local_settings.py
```

Though on line 28 of settings/**init**.py the code appears to specifically direct the program to set the environment type to local.

```
  dt_key = os.environ.get('DEPLOYMENT_TYPE', 'LOCAL')
```

It's almost as if the code from the /settings/vendor_services_settings.py doesn't want to export its code because the program is running in a local environment. I've tried adding the code from this vendor_service_settings.py file to the local_settings.py file, which works up until the point which the program appears to need the actual data.

```
BUCKET_NAME = "intelligenttrading-s3-production"
    QUEUE_NAME = "intelligenttrading-sqs-production" # for production bot
    # DELAYED_QUEUE_NAME = "intelligenttrading-delayed-sqs-production"
    BETA_QUEUE_NAME = "intelligenttrading-sqs-beta" # for beta bot
    TEST_QUEUE_NAME = ""
    SNS_NAME = "intelligenttrading-sns-production"
```

'Shivving' this code into the local_settings.py file make the migration work temporarily, though again it's not a solution. I suppose my question is, how do I properly import data across files within a settings folder in Django?

I thought to just deploy a Amazon Aurora DB instance, because it might register as a production environment. Though the tutorials would have me run the same python manage.py migrate code beforehand, anyways. Would server deployment make a difference?

Comment: did you rename the settings file as stated in their docs? or just copy over what you need

Comment: I copied the settings/local_settings_template.py file over to  settings/local_settings.py

Comment: dt_key = os.environ.get('DEPLOYMENT_TYPE', 'LOCAL') - that does not mean it's specifically directing the program to set local - it's saying use 'LOCAL' if you don't find an environment variable called DEPLOYMENT_TYPE (which should be in an .env file or set using export on the OS)

Comment: Update: I'm using Python 3.6.8 - the version contemporaneous with this code's initial release. The fact that make migrations fails (on the above error) shows that this is a problem with a code, and not even a problem with a database or postgresql server configuration. (Since make migrations would 'staged' a migration, whereas migrate would actual update a database).